# Getting "doc is not a function" when writing to Firestore after creating a user

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to save the username in my Firestore Database while creating the user. I'm using Firebase (v9) with React. The code is Below.

A user is created but in the Firestore Database user is not added.

What is the way to use `setDoc` inside `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`

Can someone help me with the code?

```
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import OutlinedInput from "@mui/material/OutlinedInput";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Alert from "@mui/material/Alert";
import { Link, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

import {
    collection,
    query,
    onSnapshot,
    setDoc,
    serverTimestamp,
    doc,
} from "firebase/firestore";

import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

import { db, auth } from "../../../firebase";

import IGLogo from "../../../images/instagram-logo.png";

import "./SignUpForm.scss";

function SignUpForm() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [successalert, setSuccessAlert] = useState(undefined);
    const [failalert, setFailAlert] = useState(undefined);
    //const [user, setUser] = useState(undefined);

    useEffect(() => {
        const timeId = setTimeout(() => {
            // After 3 seconds set the show value to false
            setSuccessAlert(undefined);
        }, 3000);

        return () => {
            clearTimeout(timeId);
        };
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        const timeId = setTimeout(() => {
            // After 3 seconds set the show value to false
            setFailAlert(undefined);
        }, 3000);

        return () => {
            clearTimeout(timeId);
        };
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        const timeId = setTimeout(() => {
            // After 3 seconds set the show value to false
            setFailAlert(undefined);
        }, 3000);

        return () => {
            clearTimeout(timeId);
        };
    });

    const instagramSignUp = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const q = query(collection(db, "users"));
        onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
                if (doc.id === username) {
                    setFailAlert({ type: "userexist" });
                } else {
                    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
                        .then((userCreated) => {
                            setDoc(doc(db, "users", username), {
                                timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
                            })
                                .then(() => {
                                    setSuccessAlert({ type: "success" });
                                    console.log("user created in collection");
                                })
                                .catch((error) => {
                                    console.log(error.message);
                                });
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            console.log(
                                "createUserWithEmailAndPassword = " +
                                    error.message
                            );
                        });
                }
            });
        });
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div className="component__signupalerts">
                {successalert?.type === "success" && (
                    <Alert variant="filled" severity="success">
                        Account Created Successfully. Please check your Email
                        for Verification.
                    </Alert>
                )}

                {failalert?.type === "userexist" && (
                    <Alert variant="filled" severity="error">
                        Username already taken
                    </Alert>
                )}
            </div>
            <div className="component__signupform">
                <img src={IGLogo} alt="" />
                <Box component="form" className="component__signupform--box">
                    <OutlinedInput
                        className="component__loginform--input"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Username"
                        value={username}
                        onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <OutlinedInput
                        className="component__signupform--input"
                        type="email"
                        placeholder="Email"
                        value={email}
                        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <OutlinedInput
                        className="component__signupform--input"
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="password"
                        value={password}
                        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <Button
                        className="component__signupform--button"
                        type="submit"
                        variant="contained"
                        onClick={instagramSignUp}
                    >
                        Sign Up
                    </Button>
                    <Link to="/" className="component__signupform--button">
                        Sign In
                    </Link>
                </Box>
            </div>
            <Outlet />
        </>
    );
}

export default SignUpForm;
```

[Console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ok8ir.png) "doc is not a function"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have two definitions of `doc` in your code:

1. First you `import { ...., doc, ... } from "firebase/firestore";`.
2. Then you also define it in `querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {`.

The `doc` in that second line hides the one that you imported.

The easiest fix is to name the variable of `forEach` something else:

```
onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((docSnapshot) => {
        if (docSnapshot.id === username) {
            ...
```